# Samsung A30s is incompatible with ARCore even with Google requirements

Tags: android, arcore

Samsung A30 and A30s have the same CPU and GPU and RAM (in my country) but even so the A30s is not compatible with ARCore.

Does anyone have a guess?

Comment: My guess is that either something is lacking (screen resolution, thermal performance, some calibration), or Samsung/Google didn't want to pay for its qualification. Related: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/263 and https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/973 indicating that more devices are needed for calibration qualification.

Comment: thanks for the info i appreciate. Is there any way to request Google to add or review the device?

Comment: Sorry no idea. Given the large number of Samsung devices that support ARCore, you are better off obtaining an existing one for development/testing.

Comment: Thanks mate unfortunately I can't afford It now I think I'll try to install the apk via apkmirror